# Skip active class for certain elements when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following problem:

I wanted to implement some logic to set the active class on list elements in my navigation bar while scrolling. I used this snippet:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() + 100;
  $('#nav-menu a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    currLink = currLink.parent();
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos) { //&& refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos
      $('.nav > li').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

It works fine when I scroll and therefore also when I click on a link inside the navigation bar. Assume I have 5 links that refer to 5 different div's. Let's say I am currently at the position of the first div.
Now I click at the last link and it scrolls through the div's. But now every link in between gains the active class as I am scrolling.
Can you suggest a workaround  to skip the links in between ?

EDIT: This is the click-to-scroll code part:

```
// Page scroll
$('a.page-scroll').click(function () {
  $(".nav > li").removeClass("active");
  // $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
      }, 900);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see the click-to-scroll code here (only the scroll detection code), but I might try adding a class to the `body` (like `.scrolling`) when you click-to-scroll, and removing the class when the scroll animation is completed. Then in the above code, you could check if `body` has the class `.scrolling` and not execute the code - and instead you'd add the `.active` class manually in the callback of the click-to-scroll, when you remove the body class.

Comment: @CapitalQ edited the question by adding the code for scrolling to something. The problem is, how do I add your approach to this solution? The problem is that it always compares the div's with the links and as soon I scroll (and automatically reach a div) it sets the active class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code per my comment on your question above. Let me know if this is working. I commented my modifications so you can CMD/CTRL+F for `--CapitalQ`.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() + 100;
    $('#nav-menu a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        currLink = currLink.parent();
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos) {
            $('.nav > li').removeClass("active");

            // added a check here to only add "active" if body not scrolling --CapitalQ
            if (!$('body').hasClass('scrolling')) {
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
        }
        else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});

$('a.page-scroll').click(function () {

    // Add scrolling class to body --CapitalQ
    $('body').addClass('scrolling');

    $(".nav > li").removeClass("active");
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
            }, 900, function () {

                // added callback to jQ animate function --CapitalQ
                $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: your solution is working but you have a typo. Please check the if condition! `!('body')` must be `!$('body')`. BTW thanks for your help!

Comment: Fixed! Glad it helped. :)